# Gulp: uglify in different destination folder with same hierarchy inside

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

I am a newbie of gulp, just started now. I am confused in giving src and destination to my task. What i am try to do is to create a new minify destination folder with same inside hierarchy like below.

Current Folder Structure (originals files):

```
app
-components
 --post-creator
  ---post-creator.component.js
 --post-rating
  ---post-rating.component.js
-routing_components
 --app-routing
  ---app-routing.component.js
 --user-routing
  ---user-routing.component.js
```

Minify Folder (where js file are minified):

```
minify_destination
-components
 --post-creator
  ---post-creator.component.js
 --post-rating
  ---post-rating.component.js
-routing_components
 --app-routing
  ---app-routing.component.js
 --user-routing
  ---user-routing.component.js
```

Gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src('app/components/*/*/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(components_min))
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
```

and everything else as you have it and let me know if that works for you.  In this case your components_min should replace the app folder - everything before the glob - and maintain your folder structure.